# display a dropdownlist everytime when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop down list. I have made it hidden at the start but whenever a specific button say TEST is clicked i want that list to be displayed. Also on each click I want it to be displayed. If the button is clicked 3 times then 3 drop downs and so on. At the moment the dropdown is being displayed only once when the button is clicked.
Don't bother the PHP code inside it.

```
<p>
<label for ="test">TEST:</label>
<input type="button" name="test" value="testing" onclick="display()"/>
<?php
    echo '<select name="LIVINGSTYLE" id="test">';
// some code here
    echo '</select>';
?>
</p>
```

My Javascript function:

```
function ondisplay()
{
   document.getElementById("test").style.display="block";
}
```

Comment: That should work fine, but you only have one select element, and if you'd like to create a new one on every click you should probably clone the one you have and give it a new ID. If you're trying to expand the select element to show all the options on a button click, that would be much harder.

Answer (score 1):

Your onclick handler is display() however your function name is ondisplay

Try something like this;
Try the following;

### Javascript;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showHide(obj)
{
    var div = document.getElementById(obj);
    if (div.style.display == 'none')
    {
        div.style.display = '';
    }
    else
    {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
```

### HTML;

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showHide('UMAR'); return false;">CLICK ME</a>
<div id="UMAR" style="display: none;">
Assalam-o-Alaikum !!!
</div>
```

Comment: Dear Brother.Thank you for the reply :) Jazakallah.. 
You have provided me with functionality of show/hide. That is actually not my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery solution, here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/2V9Ak/), with this you can display infinite select boxes.

```
<label for ="test">TEST:</label>
<input id="test" type="button" name="test" value="Testing"/>

$(function(){
   $('#test').click(function(){
      $('body').append('<select name="LIVINGSTYLE" id="test">'+
                       '<option value="1">Option 1</option>'+
                       '<option value="2">Option 2</option>'+
                       '<option value="3">Option 3</option>'+
                       '<option value="4">Option 4</option>'+
                       '</select>');
   });
});
```

Comment: Not working in CodeIgniter. It gives an error whenever i try to $this->load->library('jquery');